# How to define delimeter to import mongodb

Tags: mongodb, csv, mongoimport

I have a data collection, which is separated by `|` character. I am going to add the data collection to **mongodb**. So I need to separate data through `|` character. how my **mongoimport** command looks like?

Previously, I'm successfully import **csv** file through the following command.

```
$ mongoimport -d mydb -c things --type csv --file locations.csv --headerline
```

Comment: mongoimport can handle json, csv and tsv.  You need to convert this file into csv or tsv format.

Comment: ok, if we convert to the csv file, how can I separate fields with '|' pipeline character

Comment: "csv" = comma separated.

Comment: Can't we use csv file to separate with '|', or it is only able to separate with ','

Comment: By definition, the "c" in csv stands for "comma".

Answer (score 12):

`mongoimport` supports either JSON, CSV (comma separated values) or TSV (tab separated values). The `|` character is not a valid delimiter for either CSV or TSV, so you will need to change your input files' `|` to `,` or a tab, and specify `--type` accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

mongodb could actually treat a | seperated record in a .unl, .txt, .csv

Just make sure you do this in the format below. For the specified mentioned extensions use the `--type csv`:

```
mongoimport -c <table_name> -d <database_name> --mode upsert --file <filename> --type csv --headerline
```